# SQLite3 Error in Python after run on LOCALHOST; works in CONSOLE

Tags: python, sqlite, localhost, pycharm

## EDIT:

When i run ... in the Chrome-Werkzeug:

> print os.getcwd()
>
> > C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.6\jre\jre\bin.

that is the wrong folder. why is that and what do i do about it? –

### Edit End

## **Original Post:**

I have created and populated a `sqllite database` in a `Python` + `Flask` + `SQLAlchemy` app.

When I run the `DBHandl.getData()` in my console, I get the data. There is Connection and I can both read and write.

But when I use `Pycharm` to run the app at localhost:5000 I can not connect and get this error:

> OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file

None of the usual errors aply. No funny charakters, no access-restrictions, no typos. I created the /temp/ folder and checked if it is write-protected.I run pycharm as an admin on win8.

As I said, data-access (read and write) WORKS in my console.

```
Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine("sqlite:///temp/database.db")
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

**more Imports, DB-Setup & Classes**

class DBHandl():
    @classmethod
    def getData(self):  # Return Personen + Adressen
        q = session.query(Person, Address).filter(Person.id == Address.person_id).all()
        return q

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    q = DBHandl.getData()
    return render_template("home.html", list=q)
```

Is the problem that sqlite can not be run on localhost? or do i have to setup the db again?

Comment: I think the db opening code is required? It might be a case of pycharm running the script from a different location casuing relative paths to be off. Just a thought.

Comment: what would be the solution for that?

Comment: Are you using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: yes, sqlalchemy and flask

Comment: @FinnFrotscher I couldn't offer advice untill i saw the code tbh. You could `print  os.getcwd()` and see if the script is running from the correct folder.

Comment: @Noelkd when I type `print os.getcwd()` in the console, i get the right path back.

Comment: NO! it is not! i ran it again in the Chrome window debugger.    >>> print os.getcwd()
 >>> C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.6\jre\jre\bin. that is the wrong folder. why is that and what do i do about it?